# Android Studio Designer Problern (Phone appear to be blue)

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in programming and when I am using Android Studio, the designer for the phone is blue. I have no idea what just happened. I'm using Android Studio 2.2. Can someone please help me solve this problem, i will appreciate it.

*Image Of Android Studio On The Right:*

[Image Of Android Studio On The Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcC9v.jpg)

Comment: That is a feature of the new version, you should get 2 layouts, one blue one - on mine it's on the right, showing you the object names, and another layout on the left with the usual object design. I've not looked for an option to turn one of them off.

Comment: So what do i need to do to get back the normal layout? @RichardGoodman

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature which was introduce in Android Studio 2.2. It's called `BluePrint` Editor.

You can turn it off by selecting **option 1** from below image in Android Studio.

[image]

For more info refer this [developer site.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help,